# Почему Hibernate получает записи множеством select запросов вместо одного?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

Вот мои entity:

```java
@Entity
public class ProductStateEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private ProductEntity product;

    // остальные поля
}


@Entity
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    // остальные поля
}
```

---

Если я делаю запрос таким образом:

```java
session.get(ProductStateEntity.class, 10);
```

SQL формируется таким образом:

```sql
SELECT product_states.id, product_states.product_id, products.id, -- остальные колонки
FROM product_states
INNER JOIN products ON product_states.product_id=products.id
WHERE product_states.id=10
```

Пока что все хорошо, используется `INNER JOIN`.

---

Если же сделать запрос таким образом:

```java
session.createQuery("from ProductStateEntity where id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", 10)
            .list()
```

SQL формируется таким образом:

```sql
SELECT product_states.id, product_states.product_id, -- остальные колонки
FROM product_states
WHERE product_states.id=10;

SELECT products.id, -- остальные колонки
FROM products
WHERE products.id=10
```

В этом случае делается 2 запроса. Сначала делается запрос в product_states, а потом в products.

---

Это еще не все, теперь мы сделаем такой запрос, который получает сразу 4 записи по 4 id:

```java
session.createQuery("from ProductStateEntity where id in :ids")
            .setParameter("ids", Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 13))
            .list();
```

SQL формируется таким образом:

```sql
SELECT product_states.id, product_states.product_id, -- остальные колонки
FROM product_states
WHERE product_states.id IN (10, 11, 12, 13);

SELECT products.id, -- остальные колонки
FROM products
WHERE products.id=10;

SELECT products.id, -- остальные колонки
FROM products
WHERE products.id=11;

SELECT products.id, -- остальные колонки
FROM products
WHERE products.id=12;

SELECT products.id, -- остальные колонки
FROM products
WHERE products.id=13;
```

В этом случае делается 5 запросов. Сначала делается запрос в product_states, получаются id всех products, а потом делается по 1 запросу на получение каждого из 4 products.

---

Добавим `join fetch` в предыдущий запрос:

```java
session.createQuery("from ProductStateEntity p join fetch p.product where p.id in :ids")
            .setParameter("ids", Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 13))
            .list();
```

SQL формируется таким образом:

```sql
SELECT product_states.id, products.id, product_states.product_id, -- остальные колонки
FROM product_states
INNER JOIN products ON product_states.product_id=products.id
WHERE product_states.id IN (10, 11, 12, 13)
```

Таким образом делается всего 1 запрос с `INNER JOIN`, то, чего я и хочу добиться.

---

И так вопросы:

1. Почему в `createQuery` нужно указывать `join fetch` явно? Нельзя ли сделать это поведение по умолчанию? Ведь один запрос с join лучше, чем много.
2. Почему без указания `join fetch` дополнительные select запросы не объединяются в один с помощью `id in (...)`? Вместо этого Hibernate делает select'ы по одному. Можно ли это настроить?

Comment: Есть хибернейтовская аннотация Fetch,  которая задает нужное поведение, но почему стандартное поведение такое, вопрос.

Comment: @RuslanGorbunov дело не в этом 100%

Comment: Может [этот ответ вам поможет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто указать `hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size`, это решило мою проблему.